# How to input data into labelled columns in a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, iteration

Now I know there are a lot of questions out there like this one, and I've looked through all of them and tried to understand them, but I can't apply it to my situation. Based on a previous answer to someone else's question, I came up with some improved code. There is a problem with it however:

```
import sys
import os
import csv

def writefile():
    print('Please enter the following: ')
    a = input('Date Of The Fixture: ')
    b = input('Stadium: ')
    c = input('Opposition: ')
    d = input('Goals For Leicester: ')
    e = input('Goals Against Leicester: ')
    f = input('Attendance: ')
    with open("LCFC_League_Results.csv","w") as outfile:
        outfile.write('Date of the Fixture, Stadium, Opposition, Goals for Leicester, Goals Against Leicester, Attendance\n')
        for row in zip('Date of the Fixture', 'Stadium', 'Opposition', 'Goals for Leicester', 'Goals Against Leicester', 'Attendance'):
            outfile.write('{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n'.format(a,b,c,d,e,f))
    Main()

def readfile():
    myFile = open("LCFC_League_Results.csv","r")
    print("Reading File ...")
    print(myFile.read())
    myFile.close()
    Main()

def Main():
    print("Write To File - A")
    print("Read The File - B")
    print("Clear File - C")
    print("Exit The Program - X")
    Choice = input("What would you like to do with the file: ")

    if Choice == "a" or Choice == "A":
        x = int(input("How many matches do you want to input? "))
        y = 0
        while y<x:
            writefile()
            y = y+1

    elif Choice == "B" or Choice == "b":
        readfile()

    elif Choice == "C" or Choice == "c":
        os.remove("LCFC_League_Results.csv")
        Main()

    elif Choice == "X" or Choice == "x":
        sys.exit()


Main()
```

The part in question is what's under the subroutine 'writefile'. If I input the data a,b,c,d,e,f the output comes out as:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Why is it outputting 7 rows; I inputted the information once and want in a single row. On the plus, at least the columns are labelled. As a side not, when it asks, 'How many matches do you want to input?', no matter what number you enter, it will always only allow you to input 1 set of data. So that's another problem.

Any help would be appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your are calling your function `Main()` you are reseting the value of `y`.

So the flow goes like this:

1. Program starts, and `Main()` runs.
2. The user gives the number `2`. `y` equal to `0`-
3. Now the function `Writefile` is invoked. When it's done, it calls `Main()` again.
4. Now another `y`, not your original `y` is set to 0.
5. Depending on what answer your user is giving, new `y` are set to `0` as long a `Main()` is called.

Also, you should change:

```
outfile.write('Date of the Fixture, Stadium, Opposition, Goals for Leicester, Goals Against Leicester, Attendance\n')
for row in zip('Date of the Fixture', 'Stadium', 'Opposition', 'Goals for Leicester', 'Goals Against Leicester', 'Attendance'):
    outfile.write('{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n'.format(a,b,c,d,e,f))
```

To simply:

```
outfile.write('Date of the Fixture, Stadium, Opposition, Goals for Leicester, Goals Against Leicester, Attendance\n')
outfile.write('{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n'.format(a,b,c,d,e,f))
```

This still has the problem that the title will always be written ...

One more point, you are importing the module `csv`, why aren't you using it?
And finally, if you keep using python, please read about `pep-8`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is writing the seven rows here:

```
for row in zip('Date of the Fixture', 'Stadium', 'Opposition', 'Goals for Leicester', 'Goals Against Leicester', 'Attendance'):
    outfile.write('{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}\n'.format(a,b,c,d,e,f))
```

If you only want one row, remove the `for` loop.